# Как локально использовать дефолтный swiper?

Tags: javascript, swiper

Хочу локально использовать swiper, но для уменьшения места хочу подключить лишь дефолтный слайдер и в ручную добавить модули с сайта, которые мне нужны. Исходя из сайта swiper так сделать можно. При подключение через npm так и делается. И я нашёл файл css для дефолтного свайпера, но файл js там есть только bundle. Я пробовал подключить js-файл core.js, но это оказалось не то. Где я могу найти дефолтный js и потом отдельно подключить необходимые модули?

Comment: возьми файлы, которые устанавливаются по дефолту командой `npm install swiper`, можно локально установить в какой-то папке, чтобы не искать

Comment: Честно говоря вообще не шарю в npm: что это и как вообще работает. Но идея хорошая, спасибо. Похоже придётся разбираться с ним. И ты не знаешь, почему там вообще нет первоначально этого файла? Причём я много версий просмотрел, его просто нету.